# Fancybox integrated into a minislide link

Tags: menu, fancybox, slide

We have a row of header menu links where a couple of them need to be fancybox popups. However, when I insert the appropriate fancybox code into the menu section the text is slightly smaller and higher than the other links (and does not incorporate the minislide background button etc.):

```
<li><a id="tip6"><strong>How it works</a></li>  <li class="line">|</li>
```

I realised for the text to appear correct it needs to have an actual `href=` link so the menu system knows it's a link (which it doesn't need to be). So of course when a link is added it overrides the fancybox operation. This is what a functional link needs to be formulated as in our menu system:

```
<li><strong><a href="link.php">How it works</a></strong></li> <li class="line">|</li>
```

I want it to function as a fancybox link though, so how can I remove the actual `href=` link and fool the menu into thinking it's a link so it's correctly displayed?

I've already tried the following, without success:

```
<li><strong><a id="tip4" href="link.php">How it works</a></strong></li> <li class="line">|</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `href="javascript:;"` to avoid overriding the fancybox functionality and still having the `href` attribute to work with your style settings so

```
<li><strong><a id="tip4" href="javascript:;">How it works</a></strong></li> <li class="line">|</li>
```

or with the `strong` tag inside the anchor (doesn't really matter)

```
<li><a id="tip4" href="javascript:;"><strong>How it works</strong></a></li> <li class="line">|</li>
```

On the other hand, if you are planning to use the same script for more than one element within the same `html` document, the better use `classes` instead of `ID`. Check http://fancybox.net/faq No. 7 for more